# What is the maximum file size and filesystem size in a 32 bit system

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

> Q: What is the largest possible size of an ext3 filesystem and of files on ext3?
>
> Ext3 can support files up to 1TB. With a 2.4 kernel the filesystem size is limited by the maximal block device size, which is 2TB. In 2.6 the maximum (32-bit CPU) limit is of block devices is 16TB, but ext3 supports only up to 4TB.

I read that the maximum file size is determined by the variable in the inode structure that holds the size field. So on a 32 bit system it is 2<sup>32</sup> is 4294967296 which is 4 * 1024 *1024 * 1024 => 4GB.
Is the maximum file size is 4GB on a 32-bit system ?

The file system size can be calculated with the no of inode blocks * size of a block.

> 12 + 1024 + 1024 * 1024 + 1024 * 1024 * 1024 = > 12 + 1024 + 1048576 + 1073741824 => 1074791436
> no of inodes.

FS size = no of inodes * block size = 1TB.

Will the max file size and the filesystem size can be the same ?

Also I couldn't understand what this statement,

> In 2.6 the maximum (32-bit CPU) limit is of block devices is 16TB, but ext3 supports only up to 4TB.

means for the maximum file size and file system size.

Comment: The maximum size depends on how you address it and how many bits you use to address, not 32 or 64-bit system

Comment: @phuclv The file size is often dealt with using a 32 bit integer on a 32 bit system. So even if the file system can support larger than 4Gb files, it's often a hard limit to consider if you want to make sure your file is compatible. Actually, even on 64 bit systems, programmers may end up using `int` for the size of a file (when they are supposed to use `size_t` or `ssize_t`).

Comment: @AlexisWilke that's wrong. If a 32-bit program doesn't support 64-bit file size then it's the programmer's bug. There's no issue using 64-bit integers in 32-bit programs and all modern 32-bit OSes have supported 64-bit size for decades. No one should use `size_t` for file size

Answer (score 2):

File systems (ext3/4, xfs ...) all have theoretical and supported [limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits). Theoretical limits (16TB on ext3) are based on the on-disk data structures of the underlying fs, supported is what has been tested (4TB). Supported limit can vary in most FS's and is tunable by the administrator depending on whether you want to have large number of large files (iso, images, etc - means less metadata on-disk) or small files (gifs - larger percent of disk is required to store FS metadata). Again the file size and file system limits are always different values.